# Having problems with inserting node in a specific order using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack, nodes

I am once again lost with HTMLAgility.

Here is the HTML string I am working with:

```
<table>...</table>
```

I am trying to correct this by adding:

```
<html>
   <head>
   ...
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
      ...
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code, I am able to get everything except the body.
Any advise?

```
HtmlNode htmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html");
if (htmlNode == null)
{
    htmlNode = doc.CreateElement("html");
    HtmlNodeCollection htmlCollection = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
    htmlNode.AppendChildren(htmlCollection);
    doc.DocumentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
    doc.DocumentNode.PrependChild(htmlNode);
}

//check if <head> exists, if not create <head>
HtmlNode head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
if (head == null)
{
    head = doc.CreateElement("head");
    HtmlNodeCollection htmlCollection = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
    htmlNode.PrependChild(head);
}

HtmlNode cssLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//link[contains(@href, " + Url.Content("/assets/global/css/reset.css") + ")]");
if (cssLink == null)
{
    cssLink = doc.CreateElement("link");
    cssLink.SetAttributeValue("rel", "stylesheet");
    cssLink.SetAttributeValue("href", Url.Content("/assets/global/css/reset.css"));
    head.AppendChild(cssLink);
}

//check if <body> exists, if yes, add style='margin:0; padding:0'
HtmlNode htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
if (htmlBody == null)
{
    head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
    htmlBody = htmlNode.CloneNode("body", true);
    htmlNode.ChildNodes.Clear();
    htmlNode.AppendChild(htmlBody);
    //HtmlNodeCollection htmlCollection = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
    //htmlBody.AppendChildren(htmlCollection);
    //doc.DocumentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
    //doc.InsertBefore(htmlBody);
    //head.DocumentNode.AppendChild(htmlBody);
    //htmlNode.PrependChild(htmlBody);
}
```

This code is giving me this -- as you can see the `<body>` is in the wrong place.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <head>
      ...
      </head>
      <table>
      ...
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `<body>` node first before adding `<head>`, because it seems that you want all content of `<html>` except `<head>` to be placed within `<body>` tag :

```
.....
HtmlNode htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
if (htmlBody == null)
{
    htmlBody = doc.CreateElement("body");
    //move all child of <html> to be child of <body>
    HtmlNodeCollection htmlCollection = htmlNode.ChildNodes;
    htmlBody.AppendChildren(htmlCollection);
    htmlNode.RemoveAllChildren();
    //add <body> to <html>
    htmlNode.PrependChild(htmlBody);
}

//check if <head> exists, if not create <head>
HtmlNode head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
if (head == null)
{
    //add <head> to <html>
    head = doc.CreateElement("head");
    htmlNode.PrependChild(head);
}
.....
```

Comment: Very nice. minor issue is that </body> ends after the first parent node. ex: <html><body><table>...</table</body><table>..</table></html>

Comment: fixed by adding `htmlNode.RemoveAllChildren();`